# const vs non-const while passing arguments to function that involve conversion

Tags: c++, arguments, implicit-conversion

I'm reading Chapter-7 of the book *The C++ Programming Language* by *Bjarne Stroustrup*. At the beginning of the chapter he writes:

> The semantics of argument passing are identical to the semantics of **initialization**. Argument types are checked and implicit arguments type conversion takes place when necessary.

In the next section, he writes

> Note that the semantics of argument passing are different from the semantics of **assignment**. This is important for const arguments, reference argument and arguments of user-defined types.

Isn't the semantics of assignment and initialization the same? It mustn't be since it makes both statements contradictory. Please tell me the difference between their semantics.

EDIT: I completely missed the point that assignment is not applicable to *constants* and semantics of initialization and assignment differ in *references*. Thanks [nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp) for pointing it out.

He follows:

> A literal, a constant, and an argument that requires conversion can be passed as a const& argument, but not as a non-const argument.

I've used non-const arguments many times and the conversion works for me (for non-reference arguments). I assume he is talking about arguments passed by reference. Is my assumption correct?

EDIT-2: Later he writes

> Disallowing conversions for non-const reference arguments (§5.5) avoids the possibility of silly mistakes arising from the introduction of temporaries.

Which makes my assumption correct. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Constants cannot be assigned to. That's the whole point of constants. They can be initialized normally though.

Comment: @nwp Thanks, I missed that point.

Comment: _"I've used non-const arguments many times and the conversion works..."_ which compiler? eg MSVC has a non-standard extension that allows this, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance

Comment: Standard GNU compiler g++. I meant if you pass `int` to the function `double sqrt(double arg)` it works.